# Drag new image into Photoshop doc at full size

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I drag a new image from a folder into a Photoshop document, Photoshop converts it to a smart layer and applies an arbitrary size to it. This is extremely frustrating when I want to add an image as a new layer at its original size - I have to open it as a new document, select all, copy, paste it into the layered document, then change that layer to a smart layer.

Is there any way to drag an image into a Photoshop document at its original size? I thought the "Resize Image During Place" setting would affect this, but apparently that's for something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open:
Edit\Preferences\General (or use keyboard shortcut: Ctrl + K on Windows)
and unchecked:

- Resize Image During Place
- Always create Smart Objects when Placing

Comment: Dang, I like them getting imported as Smart Objects but they seem to get resized regardless of whether the "Resize Image During Place" setting is checked (at least in CS5). I guess there's no way around it.